# Oil Rush Commercial PPA problem

Tags: ppa, commercial

I have bought Oil Rush from the Ubuntu Software Center but it won't install and it's not in the "Private PPA access" -list. The PPA just don't work. And I don't see Oil Rush in Synaptic.

Comment: seems that there are more people with this kind of problem, check: http://askubuntu.com/questions/146013/reinstall-commercial-software-e-g-oil-rush-steelstorm-etc

Answer (score 1):

1. Log in [here](https://store.unigine.com/accounts/login/?next=/accounts/files/) to download the Debian-package
2. After logging in, you should also find your serial key there
3. After successful downloading the package, double-click on it
4. Ubuntu Software Center should start and as if you trust this package
5. Click the install button
6. After installing, play the game

I hope this helps