# None of the software I have bought can be installed in 13.04, how can I get it all back?

Tags: apt, software-center, software-sources

I have attempted to reinstall previous purchases via the software center. I am aware that some of the trashier devs (super meat boy) have decided to drop support for Linux, so the software center doesn't allow me. It tells me that it doesn't have a package for my version of Ubuntu. Fine.

However, all of my other games (and there are quite a lot of them) harbor no complaints with the Software Center. If I try to install any of these, it correctly adds the private ppa to my sources.list. However, upon updating apt, I always get a 401, regardless of the package. This is a fresh install.

Why am I unable to use any of my bought games on 13.04?

Comment: Bah, forget it. Thanks for breaking everything!

Comment: Actually, no, I can't forget it. I've reinstalled 12.04.2 and now I'm getting 401 errors for everything there, too. Why is none of my stuff here?

Comment: You guys suck at this. Here's something for future duckduckgo-ers: http://askubuntu.com/questions/146013/reinstall-commercial-software-e-g-oil-rush-steelstorm-etc/148988#148988