# How can I redownload previously purchased Linux Format magazine on Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center, paid-applications

I bought some issues of the Linux Format magazine on the Ubuntu Software Center. I now reinstalled Ubuntu and would like to redownload the magazines. In the list, they correctly appear as "Previously Purchased", but if I try to install them, I see:

> There isn't a software package called lxf171 in your current software sources.

Also, the magazines do not appear when I click on reinstall previous purchases in the menu.

If I try to buy a new issue, everything works perfectly.

Does anyone know how can I download the magazines that I already paid and donwloaded in the past?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. I applied the method described in this answer

[Reinstall commercial software (e.g. oil rush, steelstorm etc.)](https://askubuntu.com/a/148988/117103)

And it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

In the Software Center App click File> Re-install previously purchased software. I'm not sure when the option showed up but it is present in 14.04.